# What is the mean and variance of this probability distribution?

Tags: variance, mean, density-function

I don't know if this distribution has a name or not so the best I can do is describe how it is obtained. You start with two arrays of n uniform random variables U(0,1) where n>2. I will provide a numeric example for the case of n=5 to make it easier to explain; however, n can take any value above 2.

So, for the case of n=5, the random variables for the first array may take the values

[0.8147    0.9058    0.1270    0.9134    0.6324]

and for the second array,

[ 0.0975    0.2785    0.5469    0.9575    0.9649].

You then subtract the minimum value of each array from it's respective array and obtain for the first array

[0.6877    0.7788         0    0.7864    0.5054]

and for the second,

[0    0.1810    0.4493    0.8600    0.8673].

You then divide by the new maximum, yielding for the first array

[0.8746    0.9904         0    1.0000    0.6426]

and for the second,

[0    0.2086    0.5181    0.9915    1.0000].

From henceforth I will refer to the arrays as A and B respectively. You now perform the operation 1-abs(A-B) yielding

[0.1254    0.2182    0.4819    0.9915    0.6426].

You then calculate the mean of the above array, yielding the final variable for which the probability density function of interest is obtained. I will refer to this variable as Z. For this case Z=0.4919, however, Z can of course take on any value between 0 and 1 for any n>2.

**I would like to know the mean and variance of Z as a function of n.**

On a separate but related note, I think it's worth mentioning that when I simulate 1,000,000 trials of the process for obtaining Z for n=3 in MATLAB and plot a histogram of the values obtained for Z to visualize the distribution, I obtain a distribution that is the same form as the first figure shown in this Wikipedia article about the Central Limit Theorem:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illustration_of_the_central_limit_theorem

The histogram I obtain is below
[image]

and the figure from the Wikipedia article is shown below as well
[image]

As you can see they are very similar in shape, and I doubt this is just a coincidence. Does anyone know if this particular pdf has a name that I could look up and do more research on? Sorry I know I deviated from my original question about the mean and variance as a function of n (which is still the primary thing I would like answered), but I couldn't resist pointing out the similarity between the two distributions.

Comment: From that wiki article you can see the density is just one they have choosen arbitrarily as a starting point!  So the similarity is indeed, just a coincidence.  As for your quation, I cannot see a (fast) way to find the expectation and variance analytically.  Most probably you must bwe content with approximations.